# fill values with select

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

**Update:** Here is a demonstration of the problem: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15ff5e/1

I am trying to perform a left join on the following 2 tables:

```
post_metrics

| post_id | likes |
|---------|-------|
| 'aaa'   |     3 |
| 'aaa'   |     7 |
| 'aaa'   |     8 |
| 'bbb'   |     2 |
| 'bbb'   |     4 |

post_history

| post_id | post_text |
|---------|-----------|
| 'aaa'   | 'doug'    |
| 'bbb'   | 'steve'   |
```

The results are similar to the following:

```
| post_id | likes | post_text |
|---------|-------|-----------|
| 'aaa'   |     3 | 'doug'    |
| 'aaa'   |     7 | NULL      |
| 'aaa'   |     8 | NULL      |
| 'bbb'   |     2 | 'steve'   |
| 'bbb'   |     4 | NULL      |
```

I would like to fill these NULL values with data from previous rows, such that the result is like this:

```
| post_id | likes | post_text |
|---------|-------|-----------|
| 'aaa'   |     3 | 'doug'    |
| 'aaa'   |     7 | 'doug'    |
| 'aaa'   |     8 | 'doug'    |
| 'bbb'   |     2 | 'steve'   |
| 'bbb'   |     4 | 'steve'   |
```

However, the query I'm using...

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.likes,
       @username := ifnull(p.username, @username) as username
FROM (select * from `post_metrics` WHERE post_id = @post_id) AS m
LEFT JOIN `post_history` AS p ON (m.post_id = p.post_id)
```

...is giving me the following results:

```
| post_id | likes | post_text |
|---------|-------|-----------|
| 'aaa'   |     3 | 'doug'    |
| 'aaa'   |     7 | 'steve'   |
| 'aaa'   |     8 | 'steve'   |
| 'bbb'   |     2 | 'steve'   |
| 'bbb'   |     4 | 'steve'   |
```

How can I properly fill null values from the previous rows?

These are tables with millions of rows and about 6 columns of sparse null values to fill. The 'post_text' field is not always the same for each post_id (varies occasionally), so I need to propagate those changes to following rows that have NULL.

Comment: Why doesn't a straight `LEFT JOIN` work? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/624cb/5

Comment: @Nick Here is an updated example demonstrating the problem: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15ff5e/1 There are some additional parameters that I didn't include in the original question, was trying to find the minimum example that showed the problem, I think I have it now, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your existing query is that `@username` is computed based on the unordered row output from your query. So you need to order the data first, and then do the `username` substitution (or, based on your SQLFiddle, `post_text`). So I think this query should do what you want:

```
SELECT post_id, 
       date, 
       likes,
       @post_text := COALESCE(post_text, @post_text) AS post_text
FROM (SELECT 
       m.post_id,
       m.date,
       m.likes,
       p.post_text 
      FROM `post_metrics` m
      LEFT JOIN `post_history` AS p ON m.post_id = p.post_id and m.date = p.date
      ORDER BY m.post_id, m.date) o
JOIN (SELECT @post_text := '') t
```

Output:

```
post_id     date        likes   post_text
aaa         2018-09-01  3       ccccc
aaa         2018-09-02  7       ccccc
aaa         2018-09-03  8       ccccd
bbb         2018-09-01  2       eeeee
bbb         2018-09-02  4       eeeee
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15ff5e/25)

Comment: this does indeed appear to fix the problem I was having thank you 

Comment: could you explain what the last join does exactly?

Comment: @Milo the last join is just to initialise the value of the variable `@post_text`. Dependent on your MySQL server, not initialising it might cause issues when later trying to use it in the `COALESCE` expression. It is used as a shortcut for putting a `SET @post_text := '';` statement before the `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

Try below using inner join

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.likes,
       m.username 
       from `post_metrics`  m
inner JOIN `post_history` AS p ON m.post_id = p.post_id
```

Comment: I've updated the question, this solution won't work because the columns are not common to both source tables

Comment: modified the answere - you can check now

Comment: thanks for your time so far, I've produced a minimal example demonstrating the problem I have: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15ff5e/1